# LWC Lightning-Datatable - Displaying multiple nested levels

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am trying to display data in my Lightning-Datatable where I have line items for each row. The problem is I cannot display those line items. I could use Tree Grid but I also want to display the column headers for the line items which tree grid does not do.

For example:

```
<lightning-datatable columns={columns} 
                     data={data} 
                     key-field="id"
                     hide-checkbox-column="true"
                     show-row-number-column="true"></lightning-datatable>
```

Where columns is my rows e.g:

```
const columns = [
                {
                label: 'A',
                fieldName: 'A',
                type: 'text'
                }, 
                {
                    label: 'B',
                    fieldName: 'B', 
                    type: 'text'
                }
            ];
```

But then I want to display a line item for each one of the rows which could look like:

```
const lineItems = [
                {
                label: 'A1',
                fieldName: 'A1',
                type: 'text'
                }, 
                {
                    label: 'B1',
                    fieldName: 'B1', 
                    type: 'text'
                }
            ];
```

Where the column headers are showing for both. Is this possible? I cannot find any standard components on this.

Comment: You can refer my post on `treegrid`: http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2020/05/treeview-drag-n-drop-product-catalog.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the [lightning:treeGrid](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/example). The children for each item are in a special attribute named `_children`. See the documentation (above) for all the details.